# Strange Xcode error "The role information in the response does not contain any known roles: (MEMBER)"

Tags: xcode

I'm trying to add an account to my Xcode, but I keep receiving this error. The same account on another Xcode works perfectly. I have other accounts working just fine.

The error is (as stated on the title)

> The role information in the response does not contain any known roles: (MEMBER)

Image with the error:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workaround to this problem is to add a new Admin account:

1. Create a new Apple ID (ex. support@yourcompany.com)
2. Invite this email address at https://developer.apple.com/account and click on People > Invite People > Invite as Admim
3. Add the new Apple ID to XCode > Preferences > Accounts

I'm also working with apple to resolve the bug you reported. But, at least I'm able to submit new builds of apps.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone still having this issue:

For me the bug was caused because i had an **expired developer program** together with multiple other valid developer programs. (XCode Version 7.3.1)

The apple homepage doesn't allow you to leave a developer team, that is expired (state 07/2016).

You can still leave the team by disabling the CSS that hides the button from you, with any Browser homepage analysis tool.

- Go to the expired team to "Membership"
- For Chrome right-click -> Analyse

Following steps on the screenshot attached:

- Search for "leave" within the html tree
- Click the "li" element
- search within the styles for "hide"
- disable the "disable: none" css style

Now you can leave the team as usual.

[Disabling the ng-hide style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mly9O.png)